# Is it possible to 'localize' content of transactional emails in Magento 2

Tags: email, transactions, localization, magento2

I want to have different transactional emails content depending of language. Is it possible to achieve that programatically, to create language specific content.

My website has ~50 store views/6 languages and I don't want to add separate template for every store.

UPDATE:
I don't want to translate, but to add completely different content for different languages. Random example: for all stores that use English language i want to have content "Welcome to our store", for stores that use French language i want to have content "How are you today(in French)" and so on. 95% of email content is completely the same, so i use translations for it, but the point is that i don't know how to 'fix' this 'different content' part

Answer (score 0):

Use the **`trans`** directive in email templates. Make sure no spaces for variable assigment.  Example:

```
<!-- Correct -->    
{{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}

<!-- Incorrect -->    
{{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name = $store.getFrontendName()}}
```

The `trans` directive translate strings into the configured language for your store view. For example, if an email is being sent from a store view that is configured to use the fr_FR locale, the emails are translated to French.

Should have proper configs in the following paths:

```
Stores-->Configuration-->General-->General-->Locale Options
path_to_theme_directory/i18n/fr_FR.csv
```

Please check [details on Magento's devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html#localization)

Comment: Hi Milan, that is not what i asked. I don't want to translate, but to add completely different content for different languages. Random example: for all stores that use English language i want to have content "Welcome to our store", for stores that use French language i want to have content "How are you today(in French)" and so on. 95% of email content is completely the same, so i use translations for it, but the point is that i don't know how to 'fix' this part